# Mongoose: the function "once"

Tags: mongoose

In the "Getting Started" of Mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) there is an example that use the function `once`:

```
db.once('open', function callback () {
  // yay!
});
```

but in the official documentation I don't find any reference to function `once` (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).

What is the meaning of this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Mongoose connection is an instance of [EventEmitter class](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter). From the documentation:

> Adds a one time listener for the event. This listener is invoked only
>   the next time the event is fired, after which it is removed.